# Do I need root folders if I add areas in ASP MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

If I add areas in my ASP MVC project like: Authentication, Forum, Groups, Events etc. Do I still need root Model/View/Controlelr folders or I can delete them? If not what would be example to keep this folders in root of the project?

Comment: You can delete them. If you want to avoid an Area called "common", you could put stuff in the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need the root `~/Controllers` folder. You are perfectly safe to delete it. You could also delete the associated view folder of course `~/Views/Home`. Be careful with `~/Views/Shared` as it might contain some layouts that your area uses. But of course this could also be moved to the corresponding area and completely get rid of it in the root folder.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing. Is it fine that View from one area point to a _Layout in another area or it is a bad practice.

Comment: @1110, if a Layout is intended to be used from multiple areas I would put it in the root `~/Views/Shared` folder and have both areas point to it.